# Python use __new__ with no default init

Tags: python-3.x, new-operator

I have some code below to create a Fruit object when no parameter is passed and when a parameter is passed.

For what I am trying to achieve, I get the error message `TypeError: object() takes no parameters`

```py
class Fruit:
    
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return object.__new__(cls,"empty name")
        
    def __init__(self, fruitname):
        self.__fruit_name = fruitname
```

Expected code to work.

```py
apple = Fruit("apple")
empty = Fruit()
```

Comment: Why do you need `__new__` at all? Why not `__init__` with a defaulted argument, e.g. `def __init__(self, fruitname="empty name"):` and no `__new__`?

Comment: Ah, is this what you're trying to achieve? Setting the default name for the fruit? Then yes, do exactly what @ShadowRanger suggests and lose the `__new__` method.

Comment: I think a better title for the question might be "How do I provide a **default constructor** in python?" or maybe "How do I assign a default value to an member variable when no value is passed into the constructor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following should be sufficient for what you have described:

```
class Fruit:

  def __init__(self, fruitname = "empty name"):
    self.__fruit_name = fruitname
```

The reason for the error is an improper use of `object.__new__()` (This function does not expect any parameters) which is actually not necessary here.

Comment: [`object.__new__` is an implicit `staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), you must pass in a class parameter for it to work properly. The minimal running example for `object.__new__` is `object.__new__(object)`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to subclass:

```
class Fruit(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return super().__new__(cls)
```

What you will likely see with your code is:

```
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Because you're passing an extra parameter that isn't supported.

But the `__new__` is redundant. There is no need for you to use it at all here, and unless you're doing some fancy metaprogramming stuff, it's likely you never need to override `__new__` at all.

Just intialise all your variables in `__init__`, and you should be fine.

Comment: In Python 3, all classes implicitly inherit from `object` class.

Comment: `__new__` is critical when writing immutable classes (e.g. subclasses of built-in immutable types like `int`, `tuple`, etc.), so it's not just for "fancy metaprogramming" (which I suppose the other use cases, like returning cached or singleton instances, or dynamically constructing subclasses rather than the parent class, might constitute).

Comment: True, but unless this is an X/Y question, I'm pretty sure this isn't what OP is asking ... 

And yes, they all inherit from `object`, making this `__new__` method in the example entirely redundant (even if it worked)